# "upgrading to 22.04lts" "do you want to start the upgrade screen" the screen does not display input button

Tags: software-installation

[image: Missing buttons]

As you can see portion of the display is missing, why, no answer in help I could find.

Comment: Sorry, what is missing ? Can't you click on "Start upgrade" ?

Comment: can you change the resolution of your screen to be bigger?  I'm guessing you're on 800x600, you'll need 1024x768 to see the screen correctly

Comment: Tried different screen sizes without any joy.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem here too.
This is an upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04.5 to 22.04.1.

The "Do you want to start the upgrade" window has no visible button(s) to cancel or continue (see image below).

It looks like the problem is with the "details" drop down list(s). As the list(s) expand, the main window increases in height and the buttons are pushed beyond the bottom of the screen. Trying to use tab to select the buttons didn't work.  This seems like a bug.

My Workaround:

- Shutdown/restarted Ubuntu
- Run Software Updater
- Now the Upgrade button reads "Continue Partial Upgrade"
- Continue with upgrade

[image: Do you want to start the upgrade window image]

Comment: Looks to be a simpler method than I used with the terminal use solution. many upgrades later still some problems each upgrade seems to complain about one or another thing, Matters are a nuisance but not greatly affecting use though, just slight annoyances.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to use the upgrade as the section which required an input, was missing.

Had already tried manipulating screen size but that did not result in success. The image posted is a screenshot to which I added the comment and a screenshot from the web, of the missing portion.

Gave up and used a search engine for an answer.

Took a risk and closed the computer then restarted it and used terminal method instead.

After the install was successful needed to do another partial install.

Only nuisance is the jerky mouse but I gather this is a known bug which has not been attended to.

As far as I am concerned in future will do a search first before selecting the installation method.

Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: "*needed to do another partial install*." This suggests that either your release-upgrade was actually unsuccessful, or that your system had serious problems before starting the release-upgrade.